# Find elements in one list that are not in the other

Tags: python, list

I need to compare two lists in order to create a new list of specific elements found in one list but not in the other. For example:

```
main_list = []
list_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list_2 = ["a", "f", "c", "m"]
```

I want to loop through `list_1` and append to `main_list` all the elements from `list_2` that are not found in `list_1`.

The result should be:

```
main_list = ["f", "m"]
```

How can I do it with Python?

Comment: Are you looking for elements in `list_2` that appear nowhere in `list_1` or elements in `list_2` that are not present at the same index in `list_1`?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

**TL;DR:** 
**SOLUTION (1)**

```
import numpy as np
main_list = np.setdiff1d(list_2,list_1)
# yields the elements in `list_2` that are NOT in `list_1`
```

**SOLUTION (2)** ***You want a sorted list***

```
def setdiff_sorted(array1,array2,assume_unique=False):
    ans = np.setdiff1d(array1,array2,assume_unique).tolist()
    if assume_unique:
        return sorted(ans)
    return ans
main_list = setdiff_sorted(list_2,list_1)
```

---

**EXPLANATIONS:** 
**(1)** You can use NumPy's [`setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) (`array1`,`array2`,`assume_unique`=`False`).

`assume_unique` asks the user IF the arrays ARE ALREADY UNIQUE. 
 If `False`, then the unique elements are determined first. 
If `True`, the function will assume that the elements are already unique AND function will skip determining the unique elements.

This yields the unique values in `array1` that *are not* in `array2`. `assume_unique` is `False` by default.

If you are concerned with the **unique** elements (based on the [response of Chinny84](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125943/7204790)), then simply use (where `assume_unique=False` => the default value):

```
import numpy as np
list_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list_2 = ["a", "f", "c", "m"] 
main_list = np.setdiff1d(list_2,list_1)
# yields the elements in `list_2` that are NOT in `list_1`
```

**(2)**
For those who want answers to be sorted, I've made a custom function:

```
import numpy as np
def setdiff_sorted(array1,array2,assume_unique=False):
    ans = np.setdiff1d(array1,array2,assume_unique).tolist()
    if assume_unique:
        return sorted(ans)
    return ans
```

To get the answer, run:

```
main_list = setdiff_sorted(list_2,list_1)
```

---

**SIDE NOTES:** 
(a) Solution 2 (custom function `setdiff_sorted`) returns a ***list*** (compared to an ***array*** in solution 1). 
(b) If you aren't sure if the elements are unique, just use the default setting of NumPy's `setdiff1d` in both solutions A and B. What can be an example of a complication? See note (c). 
(c) Things will be different if either of the two lists is **not** unique. 

 Say `list_2` is not unique: `list2 = ["a", "f", "c", "m", "m"]`. Keep `list1` as is: `list_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]` 
 Setting the default value of `assume_unique` yields `["f", "m"]` (in both solutions). HOWEVER, if you set `assume_unique=True`, both solutions give `["f", "m", "m"]`. Why? This is because the user ASSUMED that the elements are unique). Hence, IT IS BETTER TO KEEP `assume_unique` to its default value. Note that both answers are sorted.

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

Comment: If your lists are already ordered, this will also return an ordered list. The native solution of converting to sets and then getting the difference (solutions shown below) returns an unordered list which may make it harder to visually examine your results.

Comment: Hi, @Doubledown! Your concern has been addressed in the edited post. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 439):

You can use sets:

```
main_list = list(set(list_2) - set(list_1))
```

Output:

```
>>> list_1=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> list_2=["a", "f", "c", "m"]
>>> set(list_2) - set(list_1)
set(['m', 'f'])
>>> list(set(list_2) - set(list_1))
['m', 'f']
```

Per @JonClements' comment, here is a tidier version:

```
>>> list_1=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> list_2=["a", "f", "c", "m"]
>>> list(set(list_2).difference(list_1))
['m', 'f']
```

Comment: This is good if we only care about `unique` elements but what if we have multiple `m's` for example this would not pick it up.

Comment: That's true. I assumed the poster was looking for unique elements. I suppose it depends on what he means by "specific".

Comment: Indeed p.s. I did not down vote your answer, especially for an unclear original question.

Comment: You could write this as `list(set(list_2).difference(list_1))` which avoids the explicit `set` conversion...

Comment: No worries! Thanks @leaf for the formatting assist.

Comment: @JonClements that is a bit cleaner; I will add.

Comment: so `set() - set()` basically removes any value from the former `set()` that is in the latter `set()`, reduces the output to unique values only, and then spits it out as a dictionary?

Comment: Personnally you should go with built-in '.difference' function. The following link provides interesting examples: https://betterprogramming.pub/a-visual-guide-to-set-comparisons-in-python-6ab7edb9ec41

Answer (score 96):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
main_list = [item for item in list_2 if item not in list_1]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> list_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> list_2 = ["a", "f", "c", "m"] 
>>> 
>>> main_list = [item for item in list_2 if item not in list_1]
>>> main_list
['f', 'm']
```

**Edit:**

Like mentioned in the comments below, with large lists, the above is not the ideal solution. When that's the case, a better option would be converting `list_1` to a `set` first:

```
set_1 = set(list_1)  # this reduces the lookup time from O(n) to O(1)
main_list = [item for item in list_2 if item not in set_1]
```

Comment: Note: For larger `list_1`, you'd want to preconvert to a `set`/`frozenset`, e.g. `set_1 = frozenset(list_1)`, then `main_list = [item for item in list_2 if item not in set_1]`, reducing the check time from `O(n)` per item to (roughly) `O(1)`.

Comment: @ettanany Please beware if you try the solution as ettanany posted. I tried ettanany's solution as is and it is indeed super slow for a larger list. Can you update the answer to incorporate shadowranger's suggestion?

Comment: Would it be possible getting the index, instead of the string?

Comment: @JareBear You can use `enumerate()` for that: `[index for (index, item) in enumerate(list_2) if item not in list_1]`

Comment: @ettanany's thank you very much!! I'll implement that asap, I had done it. But your code looks so much cleaner.

Answer (score 88):

Not sure why the above explanations are so complicated when you have native methods available:

```
main_list = list(set(list_2)-set(list_1))
```

Comment: Preserving order might be the reason

Answer (score 12):

If you want a one-liner solution (ignoring imports) that only requires `O(max(n, m))` work for inputs of length `n` and `m`, not `O(n * m)` work, you can do so with [the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import filterfalse

main_list = list(filterfalse(set(list_1).__contains__, list_2))
```

This takes advantage of the functional functions taking a callback function on construction, allowing it to create the callback once and reuse it for every element without needing to store it somewhere (because `filterfalse` stores it internally); list comprehensions and generator expressions can do this, but it's ugly.†

That gets the same results in a single line as:

```
main_list = [x for x in list_2 if x not in list_1]
```

with the speed of:

```
set_1 = set(list_1)
main_list = [x for x in list_2 if x not in set_1]
```

Of course, if the comparisons are intended to be positional, so:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [2, 3, 4]
```

should produce:

```
main_list = [2, 3, 4]
```

(because no value in `list_2` has a match at the same index in `list_1`), you should definitely go with [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125939/364696), which involves no temporary `list`s or `set`s (even with `set`s being roughly `O(1)`, they have a higher "constant" factor per check than simple equality checks) and involves `O(min(n, m))` work, less than any other answer, and if your problem is position sensitive, is the only *correct* solution when matching elements appear at mismatched offsets.

†: The way to do the same thing with a list comprehension as a one-liner would be to abuse nested looping to create and cache value(s) in the "outermost" loop, e.g.:

```
main_list = [x for set_1 in (set(list_1),) for x in list_2 if x not in set_1]
```

which also gives a minor performance benefit on Python 3 (because now `set_1` is locally scoped in the comprehension code, rather than looked up from nested scope for each check; on Python 2 that doesn't matter, because Python 2 doesn't use closures for list comprehensions; they operate in the same scope they're used in).

Answer (score 6):

```
main_list=[]
list_1=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list_2=["a", "f", "c", "m"]

for i in list_2:
    if i not in list_1:
        main_list.append(i)

print(main_list)
```

output:

```
['f', 'm']
```

Comment: Like [the equivalent list comprehension based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41125957/364696), this will be slow if `list_1` is large, and `list_2` is of non-trivial size, because it involves `len(list_2)` `O(n)` scans of `list_1`, making it `O(n * m)` (where `n` and `m` are the lengths of `list_2` and `list_1` respectively). If you convert `list_1` to a `set`/`frozenset` up front, the contains checks can be done in `O(1)`, making the total work `O(n)` on the length of `list_2` (technically, `O(max(n, m))`, since you do `O(m)` work to make the `set`).

Answer (score 4):

If the number of occurences should be taken into account you probably need to use something like `collections.Counter`:

```
list_1=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list_2=["a", "f", "c", "m"] 
from collections import Counter
cnt1 = Counter(list_1)
cnt2 = Counter(list_2)
final = [key for key, counts in cnt2.items() if cnt1[key] != counts]

>>> final
['f', 'm']
```

As promised this can also handle differing number of occurences as "difference":

```
list_1=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 'a']
cnt1 = Counter(list_1)
cnt2 = Counter(list_2)
final = [key for key, counts in cnt2.items() if cnt1[key] != counts]

>>> final
['a', 'f', 'm']
```

Answer (score 4):

I used two methods and I found one method useful over other. Here is my answer:

My input data:

```
crkmod_mpp = ['M13','M18','M19','M24']
testmod_mpp = ['M13','M14','M15','M16','M17','M18','M19','M20','M21','M22','M23','M24']
```

Method1: `np.setdiff1d` I like this approach over other because it preserves the position

```
test= list(np.setdiff1d(testmod_mpp,crkmod_mpp))
print(test)
['M15', 'M16', 'M22', 'M23', 'M20', 'M14', 'M17', 'M21']
```

Method2: Though it gives same answer as in Method1 but disturbs the order

```
test = list(set(testmod_mpp).difference(set(crkmod_mpp)))
print(test)
['POA23', 'POA15', 'POA17', 'POA16', 'POA22', 'POA18', 'POA24', 'POA21']
```

Method1 `np.setdiff1d` meets my requirements perfectly. 
This answer for information.

Answer (score 3):

I would `zip` the lists together to compare them element by element.

```
main_list = [b for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if a!= b]
```

Comment: If the OP wants to compare element by element (it's unclear, the example could go either way), this is _much_ more efficient than the other answers, since it's a single cheap pass over both `list`s with a single new `list` being constructed, no additional temporaries, no expensive containment checks, etc.

Comment: @ShadowRanger this would only work for element-wise difference which is a key point

Comment: @fordprefect: Yup. [My own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126821/364696) covers position-independent differences.

Answer (score 0):

From ser1 remove items present in ser2.

## Input

ser1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ser2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

## Solution

ser1[~ser1.isin(ser2)]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question has eight other responses, one of which has been accepted by the original poster. Please describe how your answer improves upon what's already been presented.