# matching lists of objects based on attributes, and identifying the incomparables

Tags: python, list-comprehension, list-comparison

For an application I'm working on, I'm searching a directory of files, and expecting to find matching pairs of files to perform some further analysis on.

In this case, a pair is defined as matching on some subset of attributes, but differing in some other attributes.

As part of the error handling/warning, I want to identify any files found that are "incomparable," i.e. files for which the expected "partner" in the pair is not found.

I have a class of objects to store the structured attribute information, and when I read files in the directory, I store each file I find as an element in list of these objects.

Here's a silly simple example

```
class glove(object):
    def __init__(self, size, color, is_right):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.is_right = is_right

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.is_right:
            hand = "right"
        else:
            hand = "left"
        s = "{} {} {}".format(self.size, self.color, hand)
        return(s)


gloves = [glove('med', 'black', False),
          glove('med', 'black', True),
          glove('lg', 'black', False),
          glove('lg', 'black', True),
          glove('med', 'brown', False),
          glove('med', 'brown', True),
          glove('lg', 'blue', False),
          glove('med', 'tan', False)]

left_gloves = [x for x in gloves if not x.is_right]
right_gloves = [x for x in gloves if x.is_right]
```

Let's assume that there's no duplicate elements in the list, and let's define a "pair" as two `glove` objects that have matching `glove.size` and `glove.color` but different values of `glove.is_right` (i.e. one is Right and one is Left).

Now I'd like to identify incomplete pairs (perhaps into a list of `leftovers` so that I could error or warn appropriately, e.g. "No Left lg blue glove found" "No Left med tan glove found."

I've seen [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125943/1009730) that teach how to identify items "missing" from pairs of lists, but my application has a couple of complexities that I couldn't figure out how to address: linking on attributes of an object, and linking on multiple attributes of an object.

I imagine something is possible with for loops and list comprehension, but I can't quite figure out how to link it all together.

Comment: Are the items unique?  Can you have more than one "left med tan" glove, for instance?

Comment: @chrisz I only know I have a missing glove if I find one that is missing a partner. In the above example, per this definition, there are only two known missing gloves.

Comment: @Prune we're assuming no duplicates are allowed, and that there's proper protections in place to guarantee this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy if you can implement equality/hash for your class:

```
class glove(object):
    def __init__(self, size, color, is_right):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.is_right = is_right

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.is_right:
            hand = "right"
        else:
            hand = "left"
        s = "{} {} {}".format(self.size, self.color, hand)
        return(s)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, glove) and \
            other.size == self.size and \
            other.color == self.color \
            and other.is_right == self.is_right

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.size, self.color, self.is_right))


gloves = [glove('med', 'black', False),
          glove('med', 'black', True),
          glove('lg', 'black', False),
          glove('lg', 'black', True),
          glove('med', 'brown', False),
          glove('med', 'brown', True),
          glove('lg', 'blue', False),
          glove('med', 'tan', False)]

gloves_set = set(gloves)
unpaired = [g for g in gloves if glove(g.size, g.color, not g.is_right) not in gloves_set]
print(unpaired)
```

Output:

```
[lg blue left, med tan left]
```

You can also consider using [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which actually does these for you.

---

Here is an alternative that does not require implementing equals and hash, nor creating new objects:

```
class glove(object):
    def __init__(self, size, color, is_right):
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.is_right = is_right

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.is_right:
            hand = "right"
        else:
            hand = "left"
        s = "{} {} {}".format(self.size, self.color, hand)
        return(s)


gloves = [glove('med', 'black', False),
          glove('med', 'black', True),
          glove('lg', 'black', False),
          glove('lg', 'black', True),
          glove('med', 'brown', False),
          glove('med', 'brown', True),
          glove('lg', 'blue', False),
          glove('med', 'tan', False)]

# With plain dict
glove_search = {}
for g in gloves:
    glove_search.setdefault(g.size, {}).setdefault(g.color, {})[g.is_right] = True
unpaired = [g for g in gloves
            if not glove_search.get(g.size, {}).get(g.color, {}).get(not g.is_right, False)]

# Or, more idiomatically, with defaultdict
from collections import defaultdict
glove_search = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(bool)))
for g in gloves:
    glove_search[g.size][g.color][g.is_right] = True
unpaired = [g for g in gloves if not glove_search[g.size][g.color][not g.is_right]]

print(unpaired)
```

Output:

```
[lg blue left, med tan left]
```

Comment: whoa, this looks really elegant, and introduces some new-to-me concepts that I need to do some reading on

Comment: I just caught that this solution relies on creating a new glove object in the list comprehension line as part of the comparison. Any way to make this approach work if the constructor for glove doesn't actually support creating a glove object by attributes? (my real-life example constructs glove objects by parsing a file)

Comment: @mac Yes, this approach requires having the looked-for object, either created there or through some `makePair` method or similar. I can try to think of an alternative later...

Comment: @mac I've added another alternative that does not require creating objects.

Comment: Awesome. That will work well for my application. I also appreciate the original answer, I know that will come in handy some day.

Comment: @mac I've added an equivalent but more idiomatic version using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects).

Answer (score 2):

With no duplicates allowed, the problem is relatively simple.
Concatenate your identifiers:

```
self.ID = self.size + " " + self.color
```

Build left/right subsets on the ID's alone.

```
left  = {g.ID for g in gloves if not g.is_right)
right = {g.ID for g in gloves if     g.is_right)

unmatched_left  = left - right
unmatched_right = right - left
```

Now, simply reverse the key process to get the glove objects:

```
unmatched = [g for g in glove_set \
             if g.ID in unmatched_left + unmatched_right]
```