# How to print missing item of the list while using str.contains pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am filtering some data from the csv file which works fine, but while matching a list items via `str.conatin` regex in pandas it prints the result for the items which is finds but i want to tag the items which does not match like `"kpc8472", "kpc1165"` these are not present in the CSV file thus not returning any results but i need to know about those missing items to be tagged as well.

```
import pandas as pd
# server names to be searched on the file in list format    
search_list =  ["kpc2021","kpc8291","kpc8471", "kpc8472", "kpc1165"]

# sorted column list
cols = [ 'Server', 'Server Name', 'iLO FW', 'Firmware', 'Appliance Name']

# Reading CSV with filtered columns
df = pd.read_csv("Server-Inventory.csv", usecols=cols)

# match the search_list items from the column "Server Name"
df = df[df['Server Name'].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(search_list))]
print(df)
```

### DataFrame:

```
           Server                    Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware         Appliance Name
0  ENC2002, bay 10                      kpc2021   2.50 Sep 23 2016  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
1  ENC8023, bay 7                kpc8291.db.com   2.40 Dec 02 2015  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
2  enc8009, bay 12                kpc8471.db.com  2.61 Jul 27 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
3  enc1011, bay 1                        kpc8479  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.74 (10/21/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
4  enc1014, bay 1                        kpc1168  2.70 May 07 2019  I36 v2.74 (11/13/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
```

### Result:

```
               Server Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware         Appliance Name
440   ENC2002, bay 10     kpc2021  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
981    enc8023, bay 7     kpc8291  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 2
2642  enc8009, bay 12     kpc8471  1.30 May 31 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)                 ov7003
```

Thanks for the help and ideas.

**Note**: I need to tag items of the list `search_list` which is not matched!

Comment: @ALollz, Would mind placing an answer, that will help, i'm just learning :)

Comment: Sure, let me edit post.

Comment: @ALollz, edited the Post.

Comment: @ALollz, thank you 

Comment: @ALollz,  while making them for example i didn't realize i changed them now for difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.str.contains`, use `.str.extractall` to get exactly the substrings that match the items in your list. Then check which elements in the list matched to at least one thing either using `.isin` (or `set` logic).

```
pat = '(' + '|'.join(search_list) + ')'
#'(kpc2021|kpc8291|kpc8471|kpc8472|kpc1165)'

result = pd.DataFrame({'item': search_list})
result['in_df'] = result['item'].isin(df['Server Name'].str.extractall(pat)[0])
```

---

```
print(result)

      item  in_df
0  kpc2021   True
1  kpc8291   True
2  kpc8471   True
3  kpc8472  False
4  kpc1165  False
```

---

Using `.str.extractall` we get a Series of the substrings that we matched. There's a MultiIndex, the outer level is the original DataFrame index, the inner level is a counter for the number of items it matched on that line (.extractall can have multiple matches).

```
df['Server Name'].str.extractall(pat)[0]
#   match
#0  0        kpc2021
#1  0        kpc8291
#2  0        kpc8471
#Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you @ALollz, +1 and testing this to my org.

Comment: This is Nice answer but only think if could be aligned with desired output and just adding `in_df` column extra to the df

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try by comparing two list:

```
serverName_list=df['Server Name'].unique().tolist()
```

If all élément of Server Name column has thé same format, you should clean data with for example:

```
serverName_clean_list=[] 
for element in serverName_list:
    serverName_clean_list.append(element.split(".")[0])
```

And according to [Python find elements in one list that are not in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125909/python-find-elements-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-the-other#comment102211219_41125909)

```
import numpy as np
main_list = np.setdiff1d(serverName_clean_list, search_list).tolist()
# yields the elements in `list_2` that are NOT in `list_1`
```

Comment: Thank you @Renaud, let me try.

Comment: Its throwing an error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'tolist'`   for `serverName_list=df['Server Name'].nunique().tolist()`

Comment: Sorry if forgot thé argument axis=1 in  serverName_list=df['Server Name'].nunique(axis=1).tolist()

Comment: NP, but its not taking that `TypeError: nunique() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`  i beleive it work as `df.nunique(axis=1)` however +1 for the best tried.

Answer (score 0):

To return non-matches add a `~`:

```
df = df[~df['Server Name'].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(search_list))]
```

Comment: NYC Coder,  thanks for the answer, but i don't need it because i need  to tag  the Servers names which are not in CSV file from the List `search_list` apert from which are matched otherwise this will give you all non-matched Server from CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the ~ symbol:

```
df = df[~df['Server Name'].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(search_list))]
print(df)
```

Comment: Renaud , thanks for the answer, but i don't need it because i need  to tag  the Servers names which are not in CSV file from the List `search_list` apert from which are matched otherwise this will give you all non-matched Server from CSV file.