# Pandas tag the non matched list items as missing in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wanted to print all the Sever names which are in List `search_list` even if not found in the dataFrame column `df['Server Name']` Just mark the non matched values as missing.

This is just an extension to the [POST Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757457/how-to-print-missing-item-of-the-list-while-using-str-contains-pandas)

Server Names in the `Server-Inventory.csv` in the `Server Name` Section are as follows.

```
kpc2021
kpc8291
kpc8471 
kpc8474 
kpc1178
kpc1179
kpc1168
kpc8812 
kpc8813
kpc8814
```

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
search_list =  ["kpc2021","kpc8291","kpc8471", "kpc8472", "kpc1165"]
cols = [ 'Server', 'Server Name', 'iLO FW', 'Firmware', 'Appliance Name']

df = pd.read_csv("Server-Inventory.csv", usecols=cols)
df = df[df['Server Name'].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(search_list))]
print(df)
```

### DataFrame:

```
           Server                    Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware         Appliance Name
0  ENC2002, bay 10                      kpc2021   2.50 Sep 23 2016  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
1  ENC8023, bay 7                kpc8291.db.com   2.40 Dec 02 2015  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
2  enc8009, bay 12                kpc8471.db.com  2.61 Jul 27 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
3  enc1011, bay 1                        kpc8479  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.74 (10/21/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
4  enc1014, bay 1                        kpc1168  2.70 May 07 2019  I36 v2.74 (11/13/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
```

### Result:

```
               Server Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware         Appliance Name
  0   ENC2002, bay 10     kpc2021  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
  1    enc8023, bay 7     kpc8291  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 2
  2  enc8009, bay 12      kpc8471  1.30 May 31 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)                 ov7003
```

### Desired:

```
               Server Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware         Appliance Name
  0   ENC2002, bay 10     kpc2021  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
  1    enc8023, bay 7     kpc8291  2.55 Aug 16 2017  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)  OV C7000 enclosures 2
  2  enc8009, bay 12      kpc8471  1.30 May 31 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)                 ov7003
  4  missing              kpc8472  missing           missing                  missing
  5  missing              kpc1165  missing           missing                  missing
```

### Note :

Only print the values from list if matched or not matched not all CVS values which are not in `search_list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for helper column matched names, then get missing names by [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html?highlight=setdiff1d#numpy.setdiff1d) and add to filtered DataFrame by [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
search_list =  ["kpc2021","kpc8291","kpc8471", "kpc8472", "kpc1165"]

pat = '(' + '|'.join(search_list) + ')' 
df['Server1'] = df['Server Name'].str.extract(pat)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Server1': np.setdiff1d(search_list, df['Server1'].dropna())})
df = df[df['Server1'].notna()].append(df1, ignore_index=True)

print (df)
            Server     Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware  \
0  ENC2002, bay 10         kpc2021  2.50 Sep 23 2016  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)   
1   ENC8023, bay 7  kpc8291.db.com  2.40 Dec 02 2015  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)   
2  enc8009, bay 12  kpc8471.db.com  2.61 Jul 27 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)   
3              NaN             NaN               NaN                     NaN   
4              NaN             NaN               NaN                     NaN   

          Appliance Name  Server1  
0  OV C7000 enclosures 1  kpc2021  
1  OV C7000 enclosures 1  kpc8291  
2  OV C7000 enclosures 1  kpc8471  
3                    NaN  kpc1165  
4                    NaN  kpc8472
```

If need replace missing values by some value:

```
search_list =  ["kpc2021","kpc8291","kpc8471", "kpc8472", "kpc1165"]

pat = '(' + '|'.join(search_list) + ')' 
df['Server1'] = df['Server Name'].str.extract(pat)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Server1': np.setdiff1d(search_list, df['Server1'].dropna())})
df1 = df1.reindex(df.columns, fill_value='missing',axis=1)
df = df[df['Server1'].notna()].append(df1, ignore_index=True)

print (df)
            Server     Server Name            iLO FW                Firmware  \
0  ENC2002, bay 10         kpc2021  2.50 Sep 23 2016  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)   
1   ENC8023, bay 7  kpc8291.db.com  2.40 Dec 02 2015  I36 v2.52 (10/25/2020)   
2  enc8009, bay 12  kpc8471.db.com  2.61 Jul 27 2018  I42 v1.42 (06/20/2020)   
3          missing         missing           missing                 missing   
4          missing         missing           missing                 missing   

          Appliance Name  Server1  
0  OV C7000 enclosures 1  kpc2021  
1  OV C7000 enclosures 1  kpc8291  
2  OV C7000 enclosures 1  kpc8471  
3                missing  kpc1165  
4                missing  kpc8472
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, Do i need to alter the code in the post or just use mask, +1

Comment: @kulfi - I think it is about readability - it is also possible create one line solution, but here is more readable, in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion jezrael, but i want only print the Server names from the search_list if matched or even not matched (with missing tag)

Comment: @kulfi - no problem, then last paragraph solution is for you.

Comment: I see the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: @kulfi - so `print (df)` is not `DataFrame` ?

Comment: Its DataFarme indeed. `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: @ jezrael.. thank you..the first solution working , need to check second 

Comment: @ jezrael. .. accepted and big thank you, if you want to change the Question title you can chnage.