# Comparing lists. Which elements are NOT in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have the following 2 lists, and I want to obtain the elements of list2 that are not in list1:

```
list1 = ["0100","0300","0500"]
list2 = ["0100","0200","0300","0400","0500"]
```

My output should be:

```
list3 = ["0200","0400"]
```

I was checking for a way to subtract one from the other, but so far I can't be able to get the list 3 as I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could this solution work for you?

```
list3 = []
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if list2[i] not in list1:
        list3.append(list2[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list3 = [x for x in list2 if x not in list1]
```

Or, if you don't care about order, you can convert the lists to sets:

```
set(list2) - set(list1)
```

Then, you can also convert this back to a list:

```
list3 = list(set(list2) - set(list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ["0100","0300","0500"]
list2 = ["0100","0200","0300","0400","0500"]

list3 = list(filter(lambda e: e not in list1,list2))
print(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been answered here:

[Python find elements in one list that are not in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125909/python-find-elements-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-the-other)

```
import numpy as np

list1 = ["0100","0300","0500"]
list2 = ["0100","0200","0300","0400","0500"]

list3 = np.setdiff1d(list2,list1)

print(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`set` functions will help you to solve your problem in few lines of code...

```
set1=set(["0100","0300","0500"])
set2=set(["0100","0200","0300","0400","0500"])
set3=set2-set1
print(list(set3))
```

`set` gives you faster implementation in Python than the Lists...............