# How to find the value of bool

Tags: python, list, boolean

```
x =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
if x == y:
    print("Numbers found")
else:
    print("Numbers not found")
```

*I want to print the numbers which are not present in list y.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python find elements in one list that are not in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125909/python-find-elements-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-the-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in x:
    if i not in y:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is to transform both in sets and print the difference:

```
>>> print(set(x).difference(set(y)))
{6}
```

This code print numbers present in `x` but not in `y`

Answer (score 1):

```
x =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in x:
    if i in y:
        print(f"{i} found")
    else:
        print(f"{i} not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

to get not matches:

```
def returnNotMatches(a, b):
    return [[x for x in a if x not in b], [x for x in b if x not in a]]
```

or

```
new_list = list(set(list1).difference(list2))
```

to get the intersection:

```
list1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list1_as_set = set(list1)
intersection = list1_as_set.intersection(list2)
```

output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

you can also transfer it to a list:

```
intersection_as_list = list(intersection)
```

or:

```
new_list = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best option in my opinion.

```
x =[1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

for number in x:
    if number not in y:
        print(f"{number} not found")
```