# Python find elements in array A but not in array B

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the difference between the 2 arrays

```
arrayA = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
arrayB = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'])
```

I'm trying to get

```
difference = ['A4', 'A5', 'A6']
```

How can I do this, thank you

Comment: If you do not need to consider duplicates you can use `set`: `difference = set(arrayB) - set(arrayA)`

Comment: What about
`difference = [x for x in arrayB if x not in arrayA]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python find elements in one list that are not in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125909/python-find-elements-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-the-other)

Answer (score 5):

Use numpy's [setdiff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
np.setdiff1d(arrayA, arrayB)
```

Also - is there any special reason for which this needs to be a numpy array? You could simply use sets and then the minus operator: `set(arrayA) - set(arrayB)`

Comment: Great answer! But do note that `np.setdiff1d(arrayA, arrayB)` returns an empty array. The arrays need to be swapped like so: `np.setdiff1d(arrayB, arrayA)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[i for i in arrayB if i not in arrayA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python set features for this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
b = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'])
print(set(b)-set(a))
```

Output:

```
{'A6', 'A5', 'A4'}
```

Or just comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
b = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'])
print([i for i in b if i not in a])
```

Output:

```
['A4', 'A5', 'A6']
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72000483/13552470) great answer, you can use the [`np.setdiff1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) method:

```
import numpy as np

arrayA = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
arrayB = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'])

print(np.setdiff1d(arrayB, arrayA))
```

Output

```
['A4' 'A5' 'A6']
```

But the order of the elements will not be kept, as the result will always be sorted in ascending order. Observe:

```
import numpy as np


arrayA = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
arrayB = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A5']) # Swapped 5 and 6

print(np.setdiff1d(arrayB, arrayA))
```

Output:

```
['A4' 'A5' 'A6']
```

If you want to keep the order, you can use the [`np.in1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) method:

```
import numpy as np

arrayA = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
arrayB = np.array(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A5']) # Swapped 5 and 6

print(arrayB[~np.in1d(arrayB, arrayA)])
```

Output:

```
['A4' 'A6' 'A5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets:

```
difference = list(set(arrayB) - set(arrayA))
```

Output:

```
['A4', 'A6', 'A5']
```